# 2020-12-01T13:01:26.922Z to 01 Dec 2020 14:33 in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This (2020-12-01T13:01:26.922Z) is the date I am getting in api response and I have to convert in
(01 Dec 2020 14:33) this forate . Please suggest .

Comment: you want to add 1 hour and 32 mins to it?

Comment: Yes ...........

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: i have to make like this .. in above it i not coming with time 09 Nov 2020 14:33

Comment: No but it should give you enough info to figure it out.

Comment: In addition, you can use [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to parse the string into JS Date, then use `getHours()`, `setHours()`, `getMinutes()`, and `setMinutes()` to add 1 hour and 32 mins. Finally, use the method by @pilchard to format the Date object (to string).

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way would be using [`momentjs`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) library (really not, see the update below) and [`moment-timezone`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/) if the conversion is required.

```js
// Load data for required timezones.
// See: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/
moment.tz.add([
  'America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT|80 70|0101|1Lzm0 1zb0 Op0',
  'America/New_York|EST EDT|50 40|0101|1Lz50 1zb0 Op0'
]);

/**
 * Converts datetime string `datetime`
 * to timzeone `tz`
 * and applies string format `format`
 * See: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/
 */
const convertDateTime = (datetime, tz, format = "DD MMM YYYY HH:mm") => {
  return moment.tz(datetime, tz).format(format);
};


console.log('NY:', convertDateTime('2020-12-01T13:01:26.922Z', 'America/New_York'));
console.log('LA:', convertDateTime('2020-12-01T13:01:26.922Z', 'America/Los_Angeles'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.32/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since recently `MomentJS` declared that its code is already a legacy and if you don't have it in your application already, it would be wise to use [`Luxon`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) instead for the same purpose, as [proposed by PrinceJelly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65437516/1203773). Then the same solution could be ported from `momentjs` to `Luxon` as described in the code snippet below.

*An interesting observation* that the outputs of `momentjs` and `Luxon` have exactly one hour difference. Seems Luxon is smarter and takes into account daylight saving time.

If you just need to add a particular time period instead of timezone conversion, take a look at `Luxon`'s [`DateTime.plus()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/math.html) method.

```js
// Requires only
// https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.25.0/luxon.min.js


/**
* Converts datetime string `datetime`
* to timzeone `tz`
* and applies string format `format`
* See:
* - https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/formatting.html#toformat
* - https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/zones.html#setzone
*/
const convertDateTime = (datetime, tz, format = 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm') => {
  return luxon.DateTime
    .fromISO(datetime)
    .setZone(tz)
    .toFormat(format);
};

const addPeriod = (datetimeISO, period, format = 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm') => {
    return luxon.DateTime
      .fromISO(datetimeISO)
      .setZone('UTC')
      .plus(period)
      .toFormat(format);
};

const inputDateTime = '2020-12-01T13:01:26.922Z';
  
console.log('Input:', inputDateTime);
console.log('NY:', convertDateTime(inputDateTime, 'America/New_York'));
console.log('LA:', convertDateTime(inputDateTime, 'America/Los_Angeles'));
console.log('+ 1h32m:', addPeriod(inputDateTime, {hours: 1, minutes: 32}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.25.0/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to provide a clear way to show your code?
The best I could suggest is try using this library: [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/)

As Eugene suggested moment is still great to use! Although, they've discontinued their updates for awhile now, it may not be supported with newer react updates.

Here's a short demo on how to use Luxon:[CodeSandBox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/example-pix8v?file=/src/App.js:200-223)

Comment: Great highlight! They even have a link to Luxon on their website and declare they're legacy. I didn't notice this before. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/